# Stop jQuery function after 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a function  to get selected point coordinations of image and save it to variables. What I need is to select two points and then execute other functions.
This code below is working fine for getting points coordinates, but execute this function only for two points? Thanks for advice.

```
$(".bg_image").click(function(e) {
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
                    var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

                    $('<div>', {
                        'class':'point',
                        'css': {
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'left':     relativeX +'px',
                            'top':      relativeY +'px',
                            'width':    '3px',
                            'height':   '3px',
                            'background-color': '#fff'
                        }
                    })
                    .appendTo('#output');
                    console.log("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable that counts how many clicks the user perfomed on the image.

```
var count = 0;

$(".bg_image").click(function(e) {
  count++;
  if ( count <= 2 )
  {
    //execute your code
  }
});
```

Comment: This works for alternate clicks! So, you click, it won't work, the next click it works!

Comment: Looks good, removed my comment as the original question wasn't quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Add a global variable like this:

```
var clickCount = 0;
```

Each time when the `.click()` is called, increment the counter. And also check the value:

```
$(".bg_image").click(function(e) {
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount > 2)
        return false;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the click count is an option.  Another consideration is to use an array and get the length of the array.

```
var coordinates = [];


$(".bg_image").click(function(e) {

  coordinates.push([relativeX,relativeY]);

  // do some operation to make sure you didn't add the same coordinate twice

  if ( coordinates.length <= 2 )
  {
     // execute your code
  }

});
```

The downside is that it might perform a little slower (probably not perceived).

The benefit is that you are storing where you clicked, so you can use that for other parts of your code.  For instance, to do analytics, or to perform distance calculations.